# Reducing condition within an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an if statement to run some code when all the textboxes on a form are completed,

the way I check for all the textboxes to not be empty at the moment is below

```
if (txtUserId.Text != ""
                    && txtFirstName.Text != ""
                    && txtLastName.Text != ""
                    && txtCity.Text != ""
                    && txtSTate.Text != ""
                    && txtCountry.Text != "")
                {
                    // Some code
                }
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: what do you use? WPF or forms?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: Define "better."  Is the code clear, and does it do its job right now?  I would argue the answer to both of these is "yes" and that you do not need to change anything about this.  (Unless you are planning on growing the number of fields dramatically.)

Comment: Sidenote: Coming from Java I wouldn't use != for a string, but Equals() instead. Not sure if applies to C# too.

Comment: @FallenSquirrel In .NET you use normally `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: @FallenSquirrel .NET defines an overloaded operator == for string which does value comparison.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abstract the check out into a function:

```
bool IsFilled(TextBox tb) { return tb.Text != ""; }
```

Then you can either use the old, simplified code, or this trick:

```
var textBoxes = new [] { txtUserId, txtFirstName, ... };
if (textBoxes.All(tb => IsFilled(tb)) { ... }
```

This is probably more scalable the more text-boxes you get.

You could also write `textBoxes.All(IsFilled)` which works due to method-group conversion to delegate. This is *slightly* more performant, and shorter. I find method group conversion hard to comprehend and misleading, though. Other people might ask you "what does that do?" and this indicates a code smell. I do not recommend it.

Comment: Ok I also got rid of the double-negation. Was not happy with that anyway. It is questionable whether IsFilled is even necessary here but I thought maybe the check will become more complex in the future (test for white-space, ...). We wouldn't want to duplicate all of that.

Comment: Now you can reduce `textBoxes.All(tb => IsFilled(tb))` to `textBoxes.All(IsFilled)`.

Comment: I intentionally did not do that because I find method group conversion hard to comprehend and misleading. That is a personal trait of mine I guess.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextBox[] boxes = new[] { txtUserId, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtCity, txtSTate, txtCountry };

if (boxes.All(x => x.Text != ""))
{
    // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the `TextBox`es in your form.

```
private bool AreThereAnyEmptyTextBoxes()
{
    foreach (var item in this.Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)item;
            if (textBox.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Windows Forms controls, you can write this:

```
public bool AllTextEntered(params Control[] controls)
{
    return controls.All(control => (control != null) && (control.Text != ""));
}
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
if (AllTextEntered(txtUserId, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtCity, txtSTate, txtCountry))
{
    // ...
}
```

Using `params` has the advantage of allowing you to pass as many controls as you want, without having to manually write code to put them all into an array that you pass to `AllTextEntered()`.

Also note that the `(control != null)` test is probably not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reflection in these circumstances. I had come cross similar problem when I was filtering results by the user details with multiple fields. If the user does not type anything in the search boxes then the query was returning all results from the database which was not intended result. I had asked the question and meet first time with reflection.

For example:

you have a UserDetail model as below

```
public class UserDetail{

  public string FirstName {get;set;}

  public string LastName {get;set;}

  public string Country {get;set;}
}
```

Then lets assume you have the userDetail object and you would like to check to ensure that none of the properties in UserDetail object is null or empty by using LINQ.

```
return userDetail.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(userDetail) is string)
    .Select(pi => (string) pi.GetValue(userDetail))
    .All(value => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value));
```

This method will return true if none of the userDetail object string properties is null or empty. If all properties contain something then this outputs true.

your logic would be:

```
public bool AllUserDetailsContainSomething(UserDetail userDetail){

 return userDetail.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(userDetail) is string)
        .Select(pi => (string) pi.GetValue(userDetail))
        .All(value => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value));

}
```

Then you can call this method

```
if(AllUserDetailsContainSomething(userDetail)){
 //do something
}
```